# HTTP request to fill an Angular array when app load

Tags: angular

I have made a simple shoping cart app with angular 9.

I am requesting the server with HTTP request to get all the product to be listed.

Everything is working fine however the only way I can retreive the product list is when I use the click event.

the function

```
  productList : any;


  sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
        //console.log(productList);
       this.productList=productList;
    });

}
```

It seam I can't run this function inside my component but if I use a button in the HTML it is working.

```
<app-product data-ng-init="sendGetRequest()" (productAdded)="addProductToCart($event)" [products]="productList"> </app-product>
<app-cart  [products]="cartProductList" (productRemoved)="removeProduct($event)" class="cart"> </app-cart>
<button (click)="sendGetRequest()">Request</button>
```

I dont want to use a button. Before  the productList was just typed in the code in Json. But now it is getting the products from an API that query a DB.

How do I run this function when my app load not when the user click a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your function `sendGetRequest()` from `ngOninit()`

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: This worked with  this.sendGetRequest(); inside OnInit

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this..

First your class should implement `OnInit` Like this.

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit {
```

And then you can use `ngOnInit` to load something when component initializes.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
        //console.log(productList);
       this.productList=productList;
    });
}
```

You should also look https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks for life cycle hooks.